# Managing React Application State with Parse-Server Backend

Tags: reactjs, parse-platform, redux, react-redux, javascript-objects

I am building my first Javascript Web App with React. My app uses Parse-Server as a back end and I have been trying to use Redux for state management.

At the moment my app has many different Containers and Components and the data flows quite well.

I have been having trouble maintaining the state during page refreshes. So I did a bit of research on Redux and have found that you can only store immutable data.

So I am looking for advice on what would be the best practice to make my data immutable, here is an example of what I am doing at the moment:

I have a ParseObject subclass for a 'Post' object:

```
export default class Post extends Parse.Object {
  constructor(attributes, options) {
    super("Post", attributes, options);
  }

  user(){
    return this.get("user");
  }

  photos(){
    return this.get("photos");
  }

  date(){
    return this.get("createdAt");
  }
}

Parse.Object.registerSubclass('Post', Post);
```

I fetch the data like this and add it to state:

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Post);
query.skip(skip);
query.limit(10);
query.include("user");
query.include("photos");
query.find({
  success: function(posts) {
    const allPostsFetched = posts.length < 10;
    dispatch(fetchPostsDidSucceed(posts, allPostsFetched));
  },
  error: function(error) {
    dispatch(fetchPostsDidError(error));
    alert("Error: ", error.message);
  }
});
```

and in my reducer:

```
case FETCH_POSTS_SUCCESS:
return {
...state,
posts: state.posts.concat(action.posts),
allPostsFetched: action.allPostsFetched,
postFetchError: null,
postFetchIsLoading: false
};
```

So everything works fine when I access this data by using `post.user()` for example, but once I try to do a page refresh, I'll get the error `post.user is not a function`, which I am assuming is because this is a side effect. Also I am using Redux-Persist for persisting state across refreshes.

So what I would like to know is what is the best way to handle state management in my situation, here are some options I am considering/have tried:

1.
I tried using immutable.js to make the data immutable but that didn't work:

```
var imm = Immutable.fromJS(posts);
```

2.
I have tried setting values of the Post object in the constructor, but the attributes is always undefined in the constructor method so I can't access the values of the Post Object.

3.
Creating plain js objects from the parse objects and storing these in redux state instead.

I was about to try option 3 next but I though I'd check on SO first to see if there is better way to go about this first.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sounds like you would need to initialize your redux store differently when the page loads. As you pointed out it can only contain plain, immutable JS objects (via immutablejs or not), everything else has to be stored somewhere else. Especially if other classes/objects depend on some state to be working functions, they need to be rehydrated from the store's initial state or updated if the state changes. So 3. is likely your best option. As a general rule, there shouldn't be any functions or complex objects (in the OOP sense) in the store anyway.

Comment: Thanks. Ye I’ll just create a plain object for the post instead. Set the values from parse object and store that in redux instead.